# Convert layout as image (Layout Screenshot) and store in Android

Tags: android, layout, local-storage

So i want to save the RelativeLayout (360x360dp) into the phone as a picture.

Here is the code that i found online, and on stackoverflow but it does not work.

Using api 24.

```
package com.femindharamshi.instapostcreator;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText caption;
    TextView captionTv;

    Button savebtn;
    RelativeLayout image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        image = findViewById(R.id.image);

        caption = findViewById(R.id.caption);
        captionTv = findViewById(R.id.captionTV);
        savebtn = findViewById(R.id.savebtn);

        caption.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                captionTv.setText(s);
            }
        });

        savebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                saveImage();
            }
        });
    }

    public void saveImage()
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        bitmap= viewToBitmap(image);
        saveImageToExternalStorage(bitmap);

//        try {
//            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/path/to/file.png");
//            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
//            output.close();
//        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        } catch (IOException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
    }

    private void saveImageToExternalStorage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
        // immediately available to the user.
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                    }
                });

    }

    public Bitmap viewToBitmap(View view) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Yes, i have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
in my androidmanifest.

How to save the image ? What is the actual working way ? I want to store in in a the root of the main storage.

Comment: https://medium.com/@ssaurel/taking-a-screenshot-programmatically-in-android-apps-67619cb80bf8 If you want to take a screenshot of the screen read this.

Comment: Not sure if you're looking on how to take a screenshot or turn view into a image, [this](https://github.com/Muddz/PixelShot) library might help you

Answer (score 1):

Make sure u have this:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(YourActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Pedigree.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
```